# Rails model's to_param sometimes not calling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I working on project using Rails 4.1.6 now. And I have strange problem. Method to_param for my models (Product, Category) *sometimes* not calling. I use it for SEO-friendly urls.

Here is my to_param method for Category model:

```
def to_param
  puts 'I am in Category to_param'
  "#{id}-#{title.to_slug.normalize.to_s}"
end
```

I use puts for find out is this method working or no. So, when my urls looks good (**/categories/39-средства-дезинфекции**) I can see the string 'I am in Category to_param' on my server console. This is correct case and all it's great.

But sometimes I have urls like **/categories/39** for the same objects. When I look into console for this case, I don't see any prints from my to_param method form Category model.

These two cases I have on the same pages, same views and using the same helpers for category url (category_path).

Most complicated for this situation is that I can't reproduce this bug and don't see any regularity. For the same objects I have correct urls most of times, but sometimes it's not. If I restart rails server and refresh browser with clear cache – problem may out and urls will be correct again.

During my debug and research I found source code for base class. But I can't see there any reasons for the situation described above.

```
def to_param(method_name = nil)
  if method_name.nil?
    super()
  else
    define_method :to_param do
      if (default = super()) &&
           (result = send(method_name).to_s).present? &&
             (param = result.squish.truncate(20, separator: /\s/, omission: nil).parameterize).present?
        "#{default}-#{param}"
      else
        default
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also I can tell that this problem was appear, when I used FriendlyID before, using regex for clear and build slugs, and now for babosa gem. So, I think the problem is my to_param **sometimes** not calling for my model.

Comment: Most likely some `link_to`s are using id explicitly. You'll need to check those.

Comment: I have tried many ways. `link_to category_path(category)`, even write my own helper `category_correct_path` that returns `return category_path(:id => object.to_param)`. For now I did not see any ways for calling `to_param` from my model on 100% cases.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue easily? I.e - do you knwo which obejcts are causing the issue?

Comment: The problem is this issue appears and does not appear for the same list of objects. Let's say I have first page of my products catalog. We have objects with ids 1-20 for this page. So, when bug is here, we have incorrect urls for ALL of these objects. Or if bug does not appear, ALL urls are correct for the same array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the reason of this behaviour. Now it's resolved!

The reason was I have redefined to_param for Product and Category in my ActiveAdmin files:

```
  before_filter do
    Product.class_eval do
      def to_param
        puts "I am in admin Product to_param"
        id.to_s
      end
    end

    Category.class_eval do
      def to_param
        puts "I am in admin Category to_param"
        id.to_s
      end
    end
  end
```

So, when I was log in Admin panel and go to Product page – "bug" will appear on front-end views.

So, I need to remove  Product.class_eval and Category.class_eval blocks from my admin classes.